# Quartz initialization error for jobJDBCStore

Tags: java, properties, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have successfully implemented Quartz into my project using jobRamStore and am now trying to configure Quartz to use JobStoreTX for persistence of jobs. The only thing I have changed is the properties file here:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName =                 QuartzJDBC
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export =                   false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy =                    false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false
org.quartz.threadPool.class =                       org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount =                 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority =              5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread= true

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold =              60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class =                         org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
#org.quartz.jobStore.class =                        org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

#jobstoreTX configuration
#org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource =       nonManaged
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass =           org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.datasource =                    nonManaged

#non-managed datasource 
org.quartz.dataSource.nonManaged.driver =           org.postgresql.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.nonManaged.URL =              some/correct/url
org.quartz.dataSource.nonManaged.user =             someName
org.quartz.dataSource.nonManaged.password =         somePassword
org.quartz.dataSource.nonManaged.maxConnections =   30
```

During initialization of the project I am getting the following error:

```
org.quartz.SchedulerException: 
JobStore class 'org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX' props could not be configured. 
[See nested exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No setter for property 'datasource']
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:882)
at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1517)
at org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener.contextInitialized(QuartzInitializerListener.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No setter for property 'datasource'
at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.setBeanProps(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1405)
at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:880)
```

I am following the configuration specifications on the quartz website and am confused as to what I am missing. Interestingly enough this defaults to just use jobRamStore. Any help you guys could offer would be most appreciated. thanks

Comment: The issue was that "datasource" in "org.quartz.jobStore.datasource" needed to be "dataSource". Now there is no issue, it is just not working. Should I delete this question?

Answer (score 4):

The Reason I am writing this answer is so that it may help someone.
I spent almost around 5 hours figuring out the problem as there is no proper example available.

When I got the problem `No setter for property 'datasource'` is was because of this
`spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.datasource`

In the `datasource` case. It should be in `camelCase` i.e.

`spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource`

After solving this error I got another error related to

`'org.quartz.utils.C3p0PoolingConnectionProvider' could not be instantiated`

for that i had to add in my gradle import

`compile group: 'com.mchange', name: 'c3p0', version: '0.9.5.5'`

Finally I was able to run the application
my whole Application configuration is

```
 spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/anonymization-job
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver      
  quartz:
    job-store-type: jdbc
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: never
    properties:
      org:
        quartz:
          scheduler:
            instanceId: AUTO
            instanceName: quartz-demo-app
          jobStore:
            useProperties: true
            isClustered: true
            clusterCheckinInterval: 5000
            class: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
            driverDelegateClass: org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
            dataSource: quartzDataSource
            misfireThreshold: 60000
          dataSource:
            quartzDataSource:
              driver: org.postgresql.Driver
              URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/anonymization-job
              user: postgres
              password: postgres
          plugin:
            shutdownHook:
              class: org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
              cleanShutdown: true
```

Comment: I spent many hours as well, thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No setter for property 'datasource'
```

Most of the times this error is due to the fact that you have wrong version (or) missing jar between development and deployment. Check your jars in development environment and compare them with deployment environment.

Comment: Interestingly enough, eclipse was pulling in a different version than what I wanted, so thank you for making me check, not the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

May be this answer will help other one who meet this problem.
Add a propery like this:
spring:
quartz:
properties:
org:
quartz:
dataSource:
quartzDataSource:
provider: hikaricp

The reason is quartz miss the properties of connection pool.